# I am trying to load osm pbf file but it gives HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, osm2pgsql

I am using this to load my osm data

```
C:\Users\EMRANUL>=osm2pgsql -c -G -d testpostgres -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 -W mfmp -C 2000 --hstore -S  D:\M_Project\BANGLADESH\Shapefile\OSM\default.style D:\M_Project\BANGLADESH\Shapefile\OSM\nepal-latest.osm.pbf;
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.69-21289M

Password:**
```

This is the result what i need to solve

```
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm_point WHERE osm_id = $1;
 failed: ERROR:  function astext(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm...
                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Error occurred, cleaning up
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an up to date version of [osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) (0.96.0 at time of writing).

The one you are using makes references to deprecated PostGIS functions.